# Assistedservicestorefront login does not work

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created custom **assistedservicestorefront**.When I tried  to login as **asagent**,an error **"Request method 'POST' not supported"** will throw. I have tried to perform debugging it,but **AssistedServiceComponentController** has not seen by storefront. I mean, debug is useless for it but debug works for **AssistedServiceComponentRenderer**. The steps I followed are:

1. ant addoninstall ...
2. AssistedServiceComponent and related impexes
3. UserGroup and Employee impexes
4. ...additionalWebSpringConfigs...=classpath:/.... in local.properties and project.properties

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess it is related to bean called springSecurityFilterChain placed in storefront. When i comment the bean out, i can perform debugging in   AssistedServiceComponentController but normal login disappeared. It does not already seem the solution to remove springSecurityFilterChain.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally related to "**addOnJavaScriptPaths**" in "**javascript.tag**". When I enabled it for **assistedservicestorefront**, it works. Otherwise, it will throw the error that I mentioned above in **CsrfFilter** which is a filter of **springSecurityFilterChain**.